# Linux: Sed command output of field 5 to a file

Tags: linux

[This image is the /etc/passwd file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zue8.png)Linux: What single sed command can be used to output matches from /etc/passwd that have Smith or Jones in their description (5th field) to a file called smith_jones.txt?

Comment: you need to provide more details: format of the file, is sed required or awk/grep/... are also ok, only matched text should be in the output or the whole line/paragraph/...

Comment: How these fields are separated to identify the 5th field?. Also provide some sample file to start with and what you have tried till now.

Comment: `awk` is designed to solve that type of problem. Doing it is sed is only an exercise in understanding why `awk` (and others) are better suited to that task. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use sed, but it looks like you're referencing a standard /etc/passwd file, so something that may do what you're looking for is this:

```
cat /etc/passwd | awk -F ":" '{if ($5 ~ /Smith/ || $5 ~ /Jones/) print}'
```

So awk '{print $5}' is commonly used to print the 5th column of something piped to it, in this case the /etc/passwd file. However, as it's not tabular data, I've supplied -F argument with the delimiter ":" as that's what splits our values.

It's then a fairly easy if statement essentially saying, if this string contains Smith OR Jones in it somewhere, print it.